# Freemarker - How to iterate through a LIST of values in a LIST that is a VALUE of a Key-Value Map

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker

Consider The Following Structure

```
public class Owner {}

public class Pet{
  public List<String> getToys();
}
```

I have a `Map<Owner,Pet>` that I want to iterate through, printing out each toy for each pet.

Here is what I have so far. Unfortunately, I'm getting a parse exception:

Passed in Java Object: `Map<Owner,Pet> ownerPetMap;`

```
<#list ownerPetMap?keys as owner>
   <#list ownerPetMap[owner].getToys() as toy>
      ${toy}
   </#list>
</#list>
```

I've gotten this to work with 2.3.25 using the "key,value" notation but don't want to use that since it's still in the incubation stage. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

2.3.25-incubating is as stable as 2.3.23, so just use it. The "-incubating" suffix is required by the Apache Software Foundation for branding reasons (see Disclaimer). It has no technical meaning.

As of the solution with `?keys`, one reason it could fail is that the `owner` is not a string. But you haven't quoted the error messages, so I'm not sure what's wrong. (BTW, `something.getToys()` can be written as `something.toys`; it's shorter.)